# How to architect my project by maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

Thanks all of you to read my question!

Months ago , I had build nexus to manage my maven repository and I build an empty web project.

My goal is to create an architecture for my company. When a new project comes, I can only configure my `pom.xml` to add my frame dependency. Well, my project's frame is `springMVC`+`velocity`+`mybatis`

I separated my Java source code into four models, `groupId`, `artifectId` has been named like below:

```
groupId is __com.myproject.framework__
```

1. parent pom's `artifactId` is `com.myproject.framework-root`.
2. sub models's `artifactId` are `framework-core`, `framework-utils` and so on.

This architecture can be used when I create an empty Java web project. I only configured the pom.xml with :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It's very good, I can reference this jar package very well!

#### But framework-core's Java code uses the Spring framework. Source code of `myproject-framework-core` jar package, is as below:

Action:

```
package com.hc360.buyer.action
@Controller
public class ActiveRecordAction extends BaseAction {
    // ...      
}
```

Service:

```
package com.hc360.buyer.service
@Service
public class BuyerInfoMainServiceImpl{
    ...
}
```

This means that I must configure path into my spring config of the new empty project, such as:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hc360.buyer.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hc360.buyer.action" />
```

My question is how can I design my framework models or jar package?

Goal is that when I create a new Java web project and reference my `myproject-framework-core` jar package, I needn't have to configure my spring config like below:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hc360.buyer.action" />
```

In my mind, the best way is I only need to reference my `myproject-framework-core` jar package in this new project's pom.xml, and then it works well.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is what you want, but consider creating your own maven archetype http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html

Comment: You might want to create an own maven archetype. Google for it. The best bet should be to create an archetype from an existing project.

Comment: Hi~,thanks very much for your reply!I know some fetures about archetype.But it isn't what I want. However,thanks all the same.The method what I want is use maven to get jar package,meanwhile,I want to reference my jar package(such as myframework-core.jar) in a new java web project by writing dependencies in pom.xml ,and with no spring config(because my myframework-core.jar's service implement must be instantiate by spring's config  ).